# Please do not copy *open* questions from ELU on purpose

Tags: discussion

This is not going to be a question, but it's too important an issue to not be raised.

It's been a day, and we're already seeing lots of questions being more or less copied from ELU. *Open* questions, mind you. In fact some people seem to specialize in that.

I understand that this is something that just happens when people try to populate the site, and I understand (or at least hope) this will slow down naturally as time passes and more actual ELLers start posting their questions en masse.

However, here's the thing: if we overdo it, the site will get shut down *before* actual ELLers get a chance to start posting their questions en masse.

The choice between “which” and “that”, the grammaticality of "very unique", how the peculiar construction "be used to" works — these are all questions that *native* speakers ask all the time. We should not duplicate them here *on purpose*, on day *one*, just to get a couple rep points on a site that subsequently and rightfully gets shut down as a poor copy of ELU, before getting a chance to see the light of public beta.

And yes, some of these questions (though not all!) are also of interest to non-native speakers, and given enough time they will get asked here anyway, but that's one reason *less* to fall over our feet asking them.

This place is meant for legitimate questions that get *shut down* on ELU, not the questions that are *open* with Good Answers with BNC stats and COHA graphs and bells and whistles.

There are *tons* of closed questions on ELU. Tons of deleted ones. More get closed and deleted every day. Some are getting closed right now as we speak. If we want to pull content over rather than creating it here from scratch, *that* is the content we should be looking at. That's the whole point behind ELL, to give those questions a home.

Comment: What about questions that haven't been closed on ELU but would be a better fit on ELL?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: Sites are allowed to overlap. When a question is asked in the overlap region, it should stay put unless (a) the OP asks for it to be migrated or (b)  it is a waaaay better fit for the other site, even if it's on topic for both.

Comment: I agree. It would be daft to have the same questions open on both sites. But it is early days for this Stack and I suspect a natural migration process of users and questions will happen in time.

Comment: I asked the "used to" question as non native speaker of English. I generally find difficult for a user who is not an English native speaker know which questions are also asked from a native speaker. Until 5 years ago, I would have expected that an American could not confuse _it's_ with _its_, but then it happened to a friend of mine, born and raised in the USA. When I made her notice that she should have written _its_, she told me that _it's_ is the possessive of _it_.

Comment: I didn't copy on purpose — just failed to search ELU properly. We ought to have a "closed as duplicate of EL&U question" option. Sometimes I genuinely fail to find a question even if it's there, and then closing as a duplicate is valid and helpful to me asking.